# How do you debug a Sinatra app like a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, logging, sinatra

In my main Sinatra controller, I want to debug the params hash after it is POSTed from a form.

I have added:

```
puts params.inspect
```

and

```
set :logging, :true
```

The `params.inspect` works if everything goes well. But if an error happens before the controller is executed I'm not getting any information about the error like I would in Rails by default.

What's the best way to get useful debug info?

[This example](http://www.nickhammond.com/2009/03/28/easy-logging-with-sinatra/) did not work at all (the app wouldn't even start after I added this code):

```
configure do 
  Log = Logger.new("sinatra.log")
  Log.level  = Logger::INFO 
end
```

followed by:

```
Log.info "#{@users.inspect}"
```

Comment: how about `raise params`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try adding a before filter that prints out the parameters

```
before do
  puts '[Params]'
  p params
end
```

Comment: had to do this on inherited sinatra code.  within the erb (or haml) file ```<% p params %>``` right above anything else written to the body.  the params will appear in your console.

Answer (score 15):

My opinion is that for debug you should use configure `:development` do because some debugging flags are turned on in this scenario. So, under your `configure do` block you can enable the flags:

```
enable :logging, :dump_errors, :raise_errors
```

and for your logging facility:

```
log = File.new("sinatra.log", "a")
STDOUT.reopen(log)
STDERR.reopen(log)
```

From the Sinatra handbook:

- `dump_errors` option controls whether the backtrace is dumped to `rack.errors` when an exception is raised from a route. The option is enabled by default for top-level apps.
- `raise_errors`  - allow exceptions to propagate outside of the app
  (...)
  The `:raise_errors` option is disabled by default for classic style apps and enabled by default for Sinatra::Base subclasses.

I also use the

```
puts "something" + myvar.inspect
```

method in the middle of my controllers.

Answer (score 10):

As @jshen says, ruby-debug is a very nice tool - if you are using Ruby 1.8.

In order to use it in Sinatra, insert

```
require 'ruby-debug/debugger'
```

where you'd like debugging to start.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using Pry or the Ruby debugger. With Pry, you can use the command line to traverse your methods and variables like you would in bash.

See "[How to use Pry with Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180959/how-to-use-pry-with-sinatra)".

Comment: This is by far the most useful method of debugging sinatra apps available.

Answer (score 4):

In order to find the best way to debug sinatra app, I created a repo at github. The most useful part is step into method debug, which looks like below.

[image]

Here is the repo: https://github.com/hlee/sinatra_debugger_example

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend using ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8. It's very easy to setup and use once you learn the four or five basic commands. It will allow you to set a breakpoint where you want to inspect the params and interactively play with it like you would in IRB.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing since you mentioned your main Sinatra controller, you have more than one, which means you're subclassing Sinatra::Base rather than using a classic (top-level) Sinatra app. If this is indeed the case, a lot of the default error-handling that Sinatra does is disabled by default.

If you include `set :show_exceptions, true if development?` in the class definition, you'll get friendly error pages that include a stack trace, params, etc, instead of just an internal server error. Another option is to `set :raise_errors, false` and then include a `error do ... end` block that will run whenever one of your routes raises an error.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby Debuggers in Sinatra

You are free to use Ruby debuggers for Sinatra. The main issue is that you will need to know which Ruby Gem is used for which Ruby version. For most people now that means Ruby 2.X and [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

#### Ruby Debuggers by Ruby version

```
 Ruby Version   Gem Install      require                add breakpoint
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1.8.X          ruby-debug      'ruby-debug/debugger'   debugger
 1.9.X          debugger        'debugger'              debugger
 2.0.0+         byebug          'byebug'                byebug
```

Once you know that you must install the gem, require it in your code and then add breakpoints by typing a keyword. Taking byebug as an example:

1. install: `gem install byebug`
2. require: `require 'byebug'`
3. breakpoint: `byebug`

#### Further Reading

[Byebug project](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)

[Byebug guide to use a terminal debugger](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [debugger](http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) gem for Ruby 1.9.

To use this with your Sinatra app:

1. Add the gem to your Gemfile

   ```
   gem "debugger"
   ```
2. Install the gem by running

   ```
   bundle
   ```
3. In your main sinatra app file, add

   ```
   require 'debugger'
   ```
4. Now to debug, you just have to add the following line

   ```
   debugger
   ```

   anywhere in your code.

When the code is being executed and `debugger` is seen, code would stop and you can inspect variables, run commands (using `eval`), etc.