# How to use Pry with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pry

I am writing my first Sinatra application and would like to use Pry to inspect/debug some things going on in the application. I haven't used Pry before either, but I would like to try it out. How would I get started using Pry with my Sinatra application?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Summary

1. Use `require 'pry'` at the top of your application.
2. Call `binding.pry` in your code whenever you want to drop into the interactive session. For information on using Pry, see [Turning IRB on its head with Pry](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/) and the [Pry wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki).
3. When you are done with a particular interactive session, type `exit` or Ctrl-D; Sinatra will resume running where it left off.

### Example

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pry'

get '/' do
  @cats = rand(100)
  html = haml :index
  binding.pry
  html
end

__END__
@@index
%html
  <head><title>Hello World</title></head>
  %body
    %p I have #{@cats} cat#{:s unless @cats==1}!
```

Here's what it looks like when I start the web server:

```
C:\>ruby pry_into_sinatra.rb
== Sinatra/1.2.6 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

When I make a request in a web browser to http://localhost:4567 the console drops into the Pry debugger before sending the result:

```
From: pry_into_sinatra.rb @ line 7 in Sinatra::Application#HEAD /:

     2: require 'pry'
     3:
     4: get '/' do
     5:         @cats = rand(100)
     6:         html = haml :index
 =>  7:         binding.pry
     8:         html
     9: end
    10:
    11: __END__
    12: @@index
pry(#<Sinatra::Application:0x3300ac8>)> @cats
=> 42
pry(#<Sinatra::Application:0x3300ac8>)> puts html
<html>
  <head><title>Hello World</title></head>
  <body>
    <p>I have 42 cats!</p>
  </body>
</html>
=> nil
pry(#<Sinatra::Application:0x3300ac8>)> exit
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2011 13:25:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 96 28.5390
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2011 13:25:57] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 447 0.0010
```

### Further Debugging

If you want to be able to use traditional debugging commands, such as setting line-based breakpoints, or stepping, or breaking when exceptions are raised, see the [PryDebug](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry_debug) library by Mon-Ouie.

Answer (score 6):

**Load the application into a Pry session:**

Take a look at your `config.ru`. If it looks something like this:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'application.rb')
```

you can load your application into Pry using

```
bundle exec pry -I . -r config/application.rb
# where -I . adds current dir to load path
# and -r is the file you want to require
```

This can be done with any module or class so long as dependencies are met.

Look at this [Pry cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/lfender6445/9919357) for advanced examples of Pry usage.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer pry-debugger. However there is still trick, that you can not pry-stepping while you run sinatra under classic style.

In order to find the best way to debug sinatra app, I created a repo at github, which looks like below.

[image]

Here is the repo: https://github.com/hlee/sinatra_debugger_example

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is also Pry, but a little bit different to above. In one of the first files to run in a process, say the `config.ru` or the `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
if ENV["DEBUG"]
  require 'pry-byebug'
  # and any other Pry extensions etc
  binding.pry
end
```

Then if I want to using debugging, I run `env DEBUG=1 bin/rackup config.ru` or `env DEBUG=1 bin/rspec` (I use it a lot with the `-e` switch in RSpec) and then set break points using `break`. It means I don't have to change the code at all to drop into it.