# Drop in Single Breakpoint in Ruby Code

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, breakpoints

I am trying to find ruby code that has commensurate functionality to these lines in python:

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

These lines essentially insert a single breakpoint into my code and open up a console where I can interact with any variables.

Any thoughts on how to do this in Ruby?

Comment: For those that know Ruby but not Python, please explain what those lines do.

Comment: You should describe this code in plain english, in case we don't speak python

Comment: hese lines essentially insert a single breakpoint into my code and open up a console where I can interact with any variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) library:

```
require 'pry' # gem install pry
binding.pry   # Drop into the pry console
```

Read more here:
http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/

See also:
[How to use Pry with Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180959/how-to-use-pry-with-sinatra)

Answer (score 1):

There is Kernel#local_variables in Ruby that returns the names of the current local variables.
Check out the docs:

```
ri local_variables
```